# How to change default position of toolbar?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qtoolbar

I'm using PyQt5, QMainWindow and I want to change default position of toolbar to the right. How can I do it?

User can carry toolbar to the edges of the window using mouse, but how can I do it using program?

```py
def initUI(self):
    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Example')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the addToolBar method as shown below:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar("Example")
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.RightToolBarArea, self.toolbar)

        self.toolbar.addAction("action 1")
        self.toolbar.addAction("action 2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```